# p:dataTable rowSelect event with multi select doesn't fire

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have p:datatable as

```
 <p:dataTable id="tasktable" rows="5"  paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,25" editable="true" editMode="row" reflow="true"
         value="#{taskBean.taskList}" selectionMode="multiple" binding="#{table}" rowKey="#{currentrow[0]}" selection="#{taskBean.selectedTaskList}" var="currentrow"}">

<p:column headerText="Select" id="checkboxSelect" selectionMode="multiple" styleClass='text-md-center com-wdth-5 white'>

</p:column>

<f:facet name="header">
    <div>
        <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="button" value="Select Columns" icon="ui-icon-calculator" styleClass="btn ad-btn-danger padd mr-b0"/>
        <p:columnToggler datasource="tasktable" trigger="toggler" />
    </div>
</f:facet>
<p:column id="sno" styleClass="com-wdth-5">
    <f:facet name="header"> #{msg['CHSN']} </f:facet> 
    <h:outputLabel value="#{table.rowIndex + 1}"/>  
</p:column>
.
.
.
 <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{taskBean.onRowSelect}" update="@form"/>
</p:dataTable>
```

With **event="rowSelect"** and selectionMode multiple, With backing bean code as

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {

    System.out.println("selectedTaskList = "+selectedTaskList.size());
}
```

But this rowSelect is **never fired** and checkbox are not **selectable**, but if I **remove** selectionMode="multiple" from p:dataTable, selection enables but still event is not fired.
And selectedTaskList is just an arrayList defined globally as:
private List selectedTaskList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: 1) No [mcve] (e.g. does removing the editable, binding, css make it work?, where is the bean), 2) No version info, 3) No info about what was debugged (client and server-side). Please improve the question

Comment: Just my curiosity/ignorance, using #{currentrow[0]}, which field is used? Alphabetic / definition order? Others? Works?

Comment: @WoAiNii I am passing the data in dataTable as List of Object[], so at currentrow[0] in managed bean I am getting primary key id of row that I have passed.

Comment: ok So I added these events, <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{taskBean.onRowSelect}" update="@form" />
                                                <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="#{taskBean.onRowSelect}" update="@form" />
                                                <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" listener="#{taskBean.onRowSelect}" update="@this"/>,but this toggleSelect to select all rows gives exception of method not found

Comment: rows are selectable now after applying these events!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing other p:dataTable events. I rectified it using these events

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{taskBean.onRowSelect}" update="@this taskToolbar" />
<p:ajax event="rowUnselect" listener="#{taskBean.onRowUnselect}" update="@this taskToolbar" />
<p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="#{taskBean.onRowSelect}" update="@this taskToolbar" />
<p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" listener="#{taskBean.onRowUnselect}" update="@this taskToolbar" />
<p:ajax event="toggleSelect" process="@this" update="@this taskToolbar" listener="#{taskBean.onAllRowSelect}"/>
```

And My Backing Bean Code

```
public void onRowSelect(SelectEvent event) {
        displayTag();
    }

    public void onRowUnselect(UnselectEvent event) {
        displayTag();
    }

    public void onAllRowSelect(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        displayTag();
    }

    public void displayTag() {
        if (selectedTaskList != null && !selectedTaskList.isEmpty()) {
            hideTag = true;
        } else {
            hideTag = false;
        }
    }
```

Where selectedTaskList is the list in which I am saving selected rows of table